# Why is stevenslockandkey.com displaying a parking page?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-parking

I've registered stevenslockandkey.com for a client, through mydomain.com, set nameservers to ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com, and set A records for * and stevenslockandkey.com to point to 185.3.95.226. On 185.3.95.226, I have a simple page set up, and if I edit my laptop's /etc/hosts to point stevenslockandkey.com to 185.3.95.226, it displays more or less what I want it to. However, without munging /etc/hosts the only thing I've seen is a domain.com (not mydomain.com) parking page. I've tried waiting a few days to let updates propagate, but updates do not seem to be propagating the way I want.

What do I need to do so that stevenslockandkey.com points to 185.3.95.226 and displays what you will get if you edit /etc/hosts to point stevenslockandkey.com to 185.3.95.226 ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a caching problem with your browser.
I get the page I assume you want it to show, and not a parked page.

Try setting the laptop's DNS to 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS) and try a different browser you haven't used with stevenslockandkey.com before.

You can use an online service such as [Centralops](http://centralops.net) to check what IP domain names are publicly resolved to, and thus avoid false negatives that might have to do with your local configuration.

Answer (score 2):

DNS looks ok:

```
$ dig stevenslockandkey.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> stevenslockandkey.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7673
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;stevenslockandkey.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
stevenslockandkey.com.  3541    IN  A   185.3.95.226

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.3.1#53(192.168.3.1)
;; WHEN: Wed May  4 07:38:43 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

...and the URL looks just fine for me:

[image]

Do you have a local DNS cache? If so, have you cleared it? Perhaps your workstation or browser is hanging on to an old DNS record for the domain. Try accessing the site from a different browser, different computer, or perhaps go try from a coffee shop or the like.